# Php проблема с $value

Tags: php

Я пока новичок и наверняка всех достал с вопросами по сотовым номерам.
Появился еще один вопрос!

```
      $file_array = file("phone.txt");
      foreach($file_array as $key => $value){
      $operator[] = substr($value, 1, 3);}
```

Я забираю из текстового файла номера, которые выглядят следующим образом:

```
89291030042
89091164022
89161164017
89291030042
```

$operator[] = substr($value, 1, 3); - этим я беру преффикс оператора.

Дальше определяю в каких ключах массива хранится мегафон 
       $opkey = array_keys($operator, 929);
Принтом выводит, значение 0 и 3. Все правильно так и есть.

Дальше надо отделить мухи от катлет.  И я хочу получить отдельную переменную  с магафоновскими номерами и записать их в тхт файл.

Я попробовал следующим образом;

```
foreach($opkey as $key => $value){
  $mega = $file_array[$value];
  }
```

Разве это не логично? Мне нужны строки, под ключами ноль и три. Ну в итоге он выводит, только первый номер, а третий нет.

Помогите разобраться! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Круто. Но я уже успел удалить, так как подумал, что не в кассу...

```
$mega = array();

foreach($opkey as $key => $value){
  if(_данный_номер_мегафон_){
    $mega[] = $file_array[$value];
  }
}
```

Comment: if не уместен ведь и так ясно что в $opkey собраны ключи мегафона (929), а в остальном верно, вы перезаписываете переменную $mega вместо заполнения данных в массив $mega[] = $file_array[$value];, и вам выдает именно третий номер. Третий номер ничем не отличается от нулевого вот вы и думаете что добавляется нулевой.